# When do pictures of products get resized? How long do they stay there?

Tags: image, cache, media

I've got pictures of some products in the folder:

media/catalog/product/cache/2/small_image/168x168/9df78eab33525d08d6e5fb8d27136e95

But actually not all of them. 
That size would exactly fit for a site I try to generate (where I'd like to include product pictures).

How can I create images in that size in this folder of all products that I've got in the shop?

How have those been created that are already there?

And how long do the images stay there? Is it safe to link there from a product catalogue?

Comment: Did you manage to resolve the issue Chris?

Comment: Yes and no .. I used a workaround with a subtheme and a category. 
How the images in 168x168 folders are created, I don't know yet but the theme solution is just doing fine for me.

Comment: To close the question please add your workaround as an answer and accept it

Answer (score 1):

Whenever you call the `catalog/image` helper on a product and use the resize method the images are written to a cache path.

```
echo $this->helper('catalog/image')->init($_product, 'small_image')->resize(168, 168);
```

This roughly translates to the path you've discribed in your question.

> media/catalog/product/cache/2/small_image/168x168/9df78eab33525d08d6e5fb8d27136e95

- **media** directory
- **catalog** directory
- it's a **product**
- it's in the **cache**
- **2** is the store ID
- **small image** is the type
- **168x168** are the width and height
- the hash is an md5 of a sting obtained from concatenating some image settings

Images are kept as long as you don't flush the image cache from the backend.
So basically you can upload any size image you like in the backend, the helper will create  resized and cached versions of them on the frontend. No need for any manual actions from your end.

Comment: To add on this...the number (2 in this case) is the store id, and the hash is an `md5` of a sting obtained from concatenating some image settings (`_keepAspectRatio`, `_keepFrame`, `_keepTransparency` and others). Check the method `Mage_Catalog_Model_Product_Image::setBaseFile` almost at the end of it.

Answer (score 0):

you can resize images dynamically in magento using class

```
Varien_Image
```

I've attached a piece of code that I've used for one of my modules

```
public function resizeImage($width='100',$height='null',$imageUrl){


if($height=='null'):    /*for square images, setting equal height and width*/
    $height=$width;
else:
    $height=$height;
endif;

$folder_path=Mage::getBaseDir('media').DS.$this->_folder_name.DS.$this->_cat_id.'x'.$width.'x'.$height;
$imageName = substr(strrchr($imageUrl,"/"),1);

//$imageResized=Mage::getBaseUrl('media').$this->_folder_name.DS.$this->_cat_id.'x'.$width.'x'.$height.DS.$imageName;
$imageResized=$folder_path.DS.$imageName;

if(!is_dir($folder_path)||!file_exists($imageResized)):

    if(!is_dir($folder_path)):
    $this->createdirectory($folder_path);
    endif;
 $dirImg = Mage::getBaseDir().str_replace("/",DS,strstr($imageUrl,'/media'));

    if (!file_exists($imageResized)&&file_exists($dirImg)) :
        $imageObj = new Varien_Image($dirImg);
        $imageObj->constrainOnly(TRUE);
        $imageObj->keepAspectRatio(TRUE);
        $imageObj->keepFrame(FALSE);
        $imageObj->resize($width, $height);
            $imageObj->save($imageResized);
    endif;
$imageUrl=Mage::getBaseUrl('media').$this->_folder_name.DS.$this->_cat_id.'x'.$width.'x'.$height.DS.$imageName;
else:
$imageUrl=Mage::getBaseUrl('media').$this->_folder_name.DS.$this->_cat_id.'x'.$width.'x'.$height.DS.$imageName;
endif;
return $imageUrl;
}

public function createdirectory($folder_path){

$dir= new Varien_Io_File;
$dir->mkdir($folder_path);

}
```

replace

```
  $this->_folder_name
  $this->_cat_id
```

with your folder names and category ids

your question implies that the images are auto generated, so even if you delete them, they will be generated again.

Comment: add a comment if you're having issues